# Google compute firewalls disappears later

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall

I trying to create some firewall rules in `google compute`, everything goes well, but some time later, they are just disappears.
I tried to add rules on `default` network, and also custom created - in both cases result same.
Tried both: through web UI, and through `gcloud` tool

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that someone or something is reverting your Firewall changes, you can take multiple approaches to verify that.

1. inspect Cloud Console [Activity](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity) logs
2. same using CLI: `gcloud beta logging read "resource.type=gce_firewall_rule"`
3. check [GCE Operations](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/operations) section in Cloud Console
4. check GCE API requests in Cloud Console [Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), using this advanced filter:
   `resource.type="gce_firewall_rule"
   jsonPayload.event_subtype:"compute.firewalls"`